# how to apply "$ \varepsilon$- $\delta$" definition of limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I am self studying calculus, and i came across a University quiz that required me to:

> Use the $ \varepsilon$- $\delta$ definition of limits to verify that the $\lim\limits_{x\to\pi} 3 = 3$?

how to apply such thing
(this definition have not been mentioned in the textbook I am refereeing to (calculus life saver))

Comment: I haven't heard of a constant called "pie" .... is it $\pi \cdot e$ ?

Comment: Ok to be serious, please rewrite the expression with MathJax so that we can understand what you mean. Seems strange that one would calculate limits to a constant function, as the output is constant.

Comment: For any $\varepsilon>0$ you can choose an arbitrary $\delta$ since we always have $|3-3|<\varepsilon.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "$\varepsilon$ - $\delta$" definition of a limit is the following:

We say that $L$ is the **limit** of a function $f$ at $c$ (i.e., we say that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$) if, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that, whenever $|x-c| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.

As stated in the comments, having a constant function makes things pretty easy, at least in terms of figuring out what $\delta$ needs to be. Following is the required proof:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and set $\delta = 1$. *(In this specific case, I can choose any positive number I want for $\delta$, but I'm choosing 1 just to be concrete.)* Our function $f$ is a constant function, meaning that for all $x$, we have $f(x) = 3$. Therefore, whenever $|x - \pi| < 1$, we see that $|f(x) - 3| = |3 - 3| = 0 < \varepsilon$ as required.

If you have any questions about this proof, please ask. If it's your first time seeing an $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ proof (and it sounds like it would be), I would be surprised if it wasn't a bit confusing.

Comment: it is a bit confusing, but some google images made it clear, clever answer thanks.

Comment: I’m glad googling images made it clear! As you start to get into more and more advanced math, it’s always a good idea to hang on to some intuitive understanding of what’s going on. If you need help understanding the intuition behind limits and their definition, I’d suggest this video here: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kfF40MiS7zA (as a disclaimer: I actually haven’t watched this video myself, but I’ve seen enough of his other videos to trust him on this one.)

Answer (score -1):

For any $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta = 5.6784\times 10^{237}$.

If $|x - \pi| < \delta$ then $|3-3| = 0 < \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{x\to \pi} 3 = 3$

=====

This follows the definition *precisely*.

The definition is literally that

$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ if for any $\epsilon >0$ we can find a $\delta$ (based upon $\epsilon$) so that whenever $|x-a|< \delta$ it will follow that that $|f(x) -L| < \epsilon$.

What this means is that if we want to get $f(x)$ as close as we want to $L$ ($|f(x) - L|< \epsilon$) we can achieve that by take $x$ within a range of $a$ ($|x-a| < \delta$).  In general, the closer we want to get $f(x)$ to $L$ we will usually need to take a narrower range. (If we cant find such a range, that would mean $f(x)$ doesn't get that close to $L$ after all.  If we can *always* find a range no matter how small $\delta$ is then that means $f(x)$ gets close to $L$ as $x$ gets close to $a$.

But if $f(x) =3$ is a constant function then $|f(x) - 3| = 0$ *always* and we *always* have $f(x)$ as close to $3$ as possible.  SO to find the range $\delta$ that assures this is trivial.  $\delta$ could be *anything*.  Whatever $x$ we choose $|f(x) -3| = 0 < \epsilon$.

So I chose $\delta$ to be anything I wanted.  I like weird and ridiculous numbers, so I chose $5.6784\times 10^{237}$.